# Migrating from GCM helper library to GCM Api

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I am used to sending GCM messages from my App Server (AppEngine) to my Clients using the GCM java library GCM-Server.jar but I found is has been [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html).

Till now, I am used to send messages using:

```
    Sender sender = new Sender(Constants.API_KEY);
    Message message = new Message.Builder()
        .addData(Constants.TO, to).addData(Constants.FROM, from).addData(Constants.MSG, msg)
        .build();

    MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, regIds, 5);
    //(regIds is a list<string>
```

Also, If I browse the web, or look up some tutorials on how to use GCM from your Java Server, I can only find ones that use the deprecated method.

Even the official sample uses this method:https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java

Is there any information on how to upgrade/migrate to the new API, some example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the client library (gcm.jar) was deprecated. The server library (gcm-server.jar) is not deprecated and you can continue using it (unless you decide to connect to the newer GCM Cloud Connection Server, which is not necessary), regardless to whether you use or don't use the deprecated library in the client side.